# MVC need to generate an URL for outside application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm looking to generate an absolute URL/MENU as extension methods which redirects to other application like "www.yahoo.com"/"www.google.com".

thanks
Baaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300833/generate-full-url-in-mvc) code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Title", "Action", "Controller", "http", "www.mysampledomain.com", 
                 "_blank", new {id = paramValue}, new { @class="someClass" })
```